# Virtualbox looking for deleted GuestAddition?

Tags: virtualbox

[image]

Hey, I'm absolutely new to all this.

I need a full-screen mode, so I had installed VBoxGuestadditions. It worked nicely and well. Just now, no idea what happened, it stopped working after I returned to a grey filtered VirtualBox screen.

Here's what I've done; 
 - I deleted the `guestadditions` iso entirely (from media manager, too). 
 - Installed a new(er) version (`VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.6`)
 - In VBOX settings: Deleted optical disk and put a new, empty one
 - Launched and tried to install `VboxGuestAdditions`. Now it's telling me it failed to open hard drive file `C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`

My assumption is that it's looking for the old file and not the new one. How do I change that? I read something and have some unmounting stuff, but I couldn't get that to work. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Apt updated and upgraded. Installed dependencies

Comment: I absolutely love how several people have cared more about correcting my question than answering it.